# find indices of subsets in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

**This question is motivated by very specific combinatorial optimization problem, where search space is defined as a space of permuted subsets of vector unsorted set of discrete values with multiplicities.**

I am looking for effective (fast enough, vectorized or any other more clever solution) function which is able to find indices of subsets in the following manner:

```
t = [1 1 3 2 2 2 3 ]
```

is unsorted vector of all possible values, including its multiplicities.

```
item = [2 3 1; 2 1 2; 3 1 1; 1 3 3]
```

is a list of permuted subsets of vector t.

I need to find list of corresponding indices of subsets item which corresponds to the vector t. So, for above mentioned example we have:

```
item =

     2     3     1
     2     1     2
     3     1     1
     1     3     3

t =

     1     1     3     2     2     2     3

ind = item2ind(item,t)
ind =

     4     3     1
     4     1     5
     3     1     2
     1     3     7
```

So, for item = [2 3 1] we get ind = [4 3 1], which means, that:

first value "2" at item corresponds to the first value "2" at t on position "4", 
second value "3" at item corresponds to the first value "3" at t on position "3" and
third value "1" at item corresponds to the first value "1" at t on position "1".

In a case item =[ 2 1 2] we get ind = [4 1 5], which means, that:

first value "2" at item corresponds to the first value "2" at t on position "4", 
second value "1" at item corresponds to the first value "1" at t on position "1", and
third value "2" at item corresponds to the second(!!!) value "1" at t on position "5".

For

```
item = [1 1 1]
```

does not exist any solution, because vector t contains only two "1".

My current version of function "item2ind" is very trivial serial code, which is possible simple parallelized by changing of "for" to "parfor" loop:

```
function ind = item2ind(item,t)
[nlp,N] = size(item);
ind = zeros(nlp,N);
for i = 1:nlp
    auxitem = item(i,:);
    auxt = t;
    for j = 1:N
        I = find(auxitem(j) == auxt,1,'first');
        if ~isempty(I)
            auxt(I) = 0;
            ind(i,j) = I;
        else
            error('Incompatible content of item and t.');
        end
    end
end
end
```

But I need something definitely more clever ... and faster:)

Test case for larger input data:

```
t = 1:10;  % 10 unique values at vector t
t = repmat(t,1,5); % unsorted vector t with multiplicity of all unique values 5
nlp = 100000; % number of item rows
[~,p] = sort(rand(nlp,length(t)),2); % 100000 random permutations
item = t(p);  % transform permutations to items
item = item(:,1:30); % transform item to shorter subset
tic;ind = item2ind(item,t);toc % runing and timing of the original function
tic;ind_ = item2ind_new(item,t);toc % runing and timing of the new function
isequal(ind,ind_) % comparison of solutions
```

Comment: I haven't foudn a clear solution, but `[~,~,ib]=intersect(item(ii,:),t,'stable');` is very close to what you want, however it does not understand that repeated values are not the same item.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Add some brief explanation to text of question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve vectorizing the code, I have assumed that the error case won't be present. It should be discarded first, with a simple procedure I will present below.

**Method** First, let's compute the indexes of all elements in `t`:

```
t = t(:);
mct = max(accumarray(t,1));
G = accumarray(t,1:length(t),[],@(x) {sort(x)});
G = cellfun(@(x) padarray(x.',[0 mct-length(x)],0,'post'), G, 'UniformOutput', false);
G = vertcat(G{:});
```

Explanation: after putting input in column vector shape, we compute the max number of occurences of each possible value in `t` using `accumarray`. Now, we form array of all indexes of all numbers. It forms a cell array as there may be not the same number of occurences for each value. In order to form a matrix, we pad each array independently to the max length (naming `mct`). Then we can transform the cell array into a matrix. At this step, we have:

```
G =
     1    11    21    31    41
     2    12    22    32    42
     3    13    23    33    43
     4    14    24    34    44
     5    15    25    35    45
     6    16    26    36    46
     7    17    27    37    47
     8    18    28    38    48
     9    19    29    39    49
    10    20    30    40    50
```

Now, we process `item`. For that, let's figure out how to create the cumulative sum of occurences of values inside a vector. For example, if I have:

```
A = [1 1 3 2 2 2 3];
```

then I want to get:

```
B = [1 2 1 1 2 3 2];
```

Thanks to implicit expansion, we can have it in one line:

```
B = diag(cumsum(A==A'));
```

As easy as this. The syntax `A==A'` expands into a matrix where each element is `A(i)==A(j)`. Making the cumulative sum in only one dimension and taking the diagonal gives us the good result: each column in the cumulative sum of occurences over one value.

To use this trick with `item` which 2-D, we should use a 3D array. Let's call `m=size(item,1)` and `n=size(item,2)`. So:

```
C = cumsum(reshape(item,m,1,n)==item,3);
```

is a (big) 3D matrix of all cumulatives occurences. Last thing is to select the columns that are on the diagonal along dimension 2 and 3:

```
ia = C(sub2ind(size(C),repelem((1:m).',1,n),repelem(1:n,m,1),repelem(1:n,m,1)));
```

Now, with all these matrices, indexing is easy:

```
ind = G(sub2ind(size(G),item,ia));
```

Finally, let's recap the code of the function:

```
function ind = item2ind_new(item,t)
t = t(:);
[m,n] = size(item);
mct = max(accumarray(t,1));
G = accumarray(t,1:length(t),[],@(x) {sort(x)});
G = cellfun(@(x) padarray(x.',[0 mct-length(x)],0,'post'), G, 'UniformOutput', false);
G = vertcat(G{:});
C = cumsum(reshape(item,m,1,n)==item,3);
ia = C(sub2ind(size(C),repelem((1:m).',1,n),repelem(1:n,m,1),repelem(1:n,m,1)));
ind = G(sub2ind(size(G),item,ia));
```

**Results** Running the provided script on an old 4-core, I get:

```
Elapsed time is 4.317914 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.556803 seconds.
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Speed up is substential (more than 8x), along with memory consumption (with matrix C). I guess some improvements can be done with this part to save more memory.

**EDIT** For generating ia, this procedure can cost a lost of memory. A way to save memory is to use a for-loop to generate directly this array:

```
ia = zeros(size(item));
for i=unique(t(:)).'
    ia = ia+cumsum(item==i, 2).*(item==i);
end
```

In all cases, when you have `ia`, it's easy to test if there is an error in `item` compared to `t`:

```
any(ind(:)==0)
```

A simple solution to get items in error (as a mask) is then

```
min(ind,[],2)==0
```

Comment: Very nice example of power of vectorization in natura. Thanks!!! Regarding memory consumption of array C. Yes, in my worst case the C arrays has memory consumption =  prod(size(item))*size(item,2)*8 ~ 1GB, which is nearly non-acceptable. Do you have any idea how to reduce memory comsumption of C without performance degradation?
What about transform C to uint8 class?

Comment: What about this?
C = cumsum(uint8(reshape(item,m,1,n)==item),3);

Comment: @michal For sure using only uint8 will reduce memory consumption. For now I haven't found another way to generate matrix `ia` without turning towards 3D matrix. A way is to use `cumsum(unique(item)==reshape(item,m,1,n))` but I don't have enough time right now to find the proper way to get indices. In your case, the memory is decreased 5 times.

Comment: I will be very happy if you help me to find any better solution of my problem ...  Now I must say that I do not see any proper way how to use your hint.

Comment: @michal Drop my idea of using `unique`. IMO, the only way to do it without too much extra memory, is to do it with a for-loop: `ia = zeros(size(item)); for i=1:max(t); ia = ia+cumsum(item==i, 2).*(item==i); end`.

Comment: And what about error case you mentioned at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: Will be possible to check error over rows of item instead of unique values at t? I would like to find item row which is not compatible.

Comment: @michal I'm sure you can do it by yourself: for each value, compute per-line max and find all elements greater than the occurences in `t`

Comment: ai by for-loop dow not work! Should be: for i = unique(t(:))'

Comment: @michal Fixed, transposition missed.

Comment: Your error check is extremely time consuming. So better test is:    any(ind(:) == 0) at the end of your function.

Comment: @michal Indeed you're right! I didn't see this simple solution. I update my post accordingly. Thanks.